# Verifying Formulas of angle of a point form the origin (For All Quadrants)

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry

i want to verify that is my formulas are correct or not for finding angle of a point form the origin.

1st => (Atan(y/x) * (180/PI))

2nd => 180 - (Atan(y/-x) * (180/PI))

3rd =>  180 + (Atan(-y/-x) * (180/PI))

4th => 360 - (Atan(y/x) * (180/PI)

Comment: It would help if you learn the basics of formatting your Q. Presumably, the 1st, 2nd, etc refer to points in those quadrants. Is that correct? So if the point is $P$ and the origin is $O$ you want the angle measured anti-clockwise from the positive $x$-axis to $OP$. Correct? In that case, the first three formulae look correct. The last one needs correcting.

Comment: yes thanks for your help

Comment: then what will be the formula for the last Quadrant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formulas look ok. (except the 4th Quadrant, should be + sign)

But, instead of forcing positive atan argument, why not just do atan(y/x) ?

atan(y/x) principle angle is between $±\pi/2$

If you don't mind negative angles, 1st and the 4th Quadrant is covered.

Since period of $\tan x$ is $\pi$, for 2nd and 3rd Quadrant, just add or subtract $\pi$

If atan2(y, x) is available, it will sort out these details.
If not, you can build your own.
see Charles Petzold's blog, [Atan2 and Exceptions (and why there aren't any)](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/09/180741.html)

```
from math import atan, pi, copysign

def my_atan2(y, x):
    if x>0: return atan(y/x) 
    if x<0: return atan(y/x) + copysign(pi, y)
    if y: return copysign(pi/2, y)
    if copysign(1,x) < 0: x = pi
    return copysign(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help i get to the answer from there https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2